# Prove that: $3^{3n - 2} + 2^{3n + 1}$ is a multiple of 19

Tags: algebras

Let $~n~$ be any natural number. Prove that:
$$3^{3n - 2} + 2^{3n + 1}$$ is a multiple of $~19~$ .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is expected that when you post questions, more than the problem statement is given. You should include context such as what you have tried or where you found this problem, things that may assist us assist you. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for more tips on how to improve your question.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** One way is to proceed by induction, the base case is trivial. Assume for $n=k$ we have that $3^{3k-2}+2^{3k+1}=19p$ for some $p\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, we have that for $n=k+1$:
$$3^{3(k+1)-2}+2^{3(k+1)+1}=3^3\cdot 3^{3k-2}+2^3\cdot 2^{3k+1}=\cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is 
$$
3^{3n - 2} + 2^{3n + 1}=
\frac{27^n}{9}+8^n\cdot 2\equiv
\frac{8^n}{9}+8^n\cdot 2 \mod 19=
8^n\cdot \frac{19}{8} \mod 19 =
8^{n-1}\cdot 19 \mod 19
$$

Answer (score 1):

As $3^3\equiv2^3\pmod{19}$

$$3\cdot(3^3)^{n-1}+2^{3n+1}\equiv3\cdot(2^3)^{n-1}+2^{3n+1}$$

$$\equiv2^{3n-3}(3+2^4)\equiv0\pmod{19}$$

Answer (score 0):

For $\,n=k\!+\!1\,$ it is $\,3\, \overbrace{\color{#c00}3^{\large \color{#c00}3k}}^{\Large\color{#c00} 2^{\LARGE\color{#c00} 3k}}\!+2^{\large 4}\ 2^{\large 3k} \equiv 19\, 2^{\large 3k}\equiv 0\ $ by $\,\color{#c00}{3^{\large 3}\equiv 2^{\large 3}}\pmod{\!19}$

**Alternatively** its $\equiv 0\!\iff\!  3^{\large 3n}/9 \equiv - 2\,2^{\large 3n }\!\iff\!  (\color{#c00}{3/2})^{\large\color{#c00} 3n}\equiv -18\equiv 1,\,$ true by $\rm\color{#c00}{above}$.

Comment: Generally in problems with exponentials it is essential to understand the algebraic relationships between them, and *eliminate* those that are algebraically dependent, just as we did with $\color{#c00}{3}^{\large\color{#c00}3n}$ above.